# Creating a Drupal Sandbox

Tags: drupal, sandbox

This could be a superuser question. I'm not sure but I need to create a sandbox for an existing Drupal Site. I'm wondering if there is a tried and true way of doing this or am I going to have to try and piece together all the files I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install the Acquia or Mamp/Xammp stack on your local machine, create a new database and dump the current database somewhere.

Install the same version of Drupal and choose the new database.

Then, just copy over the current 'drupal' folder EXCEPT for the settings.php file (leave the newer one from the new install).

import the database into the new database you installed the fresh drupal locally into.

Login and should be good to go. That what I did and all is fine.